# Calculation on Trilateration in Python

Tags: python

i have 3 nodes that will send the package that consist of coordinates (latitude, longitude) and rssi value to the gateway at the same time i using the formula of *distance  = 10** ((measured power - rssi) / (10*n))* to obtained the distance. Which mean i have 3 (latitude, longitude, distance).I tried to get the distance but the unknown target location is confused.

Comment: Please add the sections of code you need help with

Comment: How can i code using the trilateration algorithm?